# How to create Blackberry Custom TAb bar

Tags: blackberry, custom-controls, tabbar

I am new to blackberry development. I want a Custom Tab bar at the Bottom of the screen for blackberry application in my project, same as the image given below.I tried the sample code given by blackberry.

But now I want to use customised UI.I have searched it on Google and didn't get any productive information on what I want ,for custom fields. Please tell me how to do it in blackberry.

Has anyone done this previously?

Please reply Anything link/code/snippet.

[image: I want Tab bar like this]

Comment: Try something like the answer of this SO question: ["Blackberry how to create Tabbar"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740541/blackberry-how-to-create-tabbar) ?

Comment: see the solution in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942225/tab-bar-in-blackberry-without-toolbarmanager

Comment: @alishaik786-do you have that code (I am asking about flicker code).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code -

```
EncodedImage e2 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("map.png");
EncodedImage e3 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("members.png");
EncodedImage e4 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("message.png");
EncodedImage e5 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("settings.png");
EncodedImage e6 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("logout.png");

EyelidFieldManager manager = new EyelidFieldManager();
HorizontalFieldManager buttonPanel = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_TOP | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);

  VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager();
  vfm.add(new BitmapField(e2.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){

        Dialog.alert("MAP");
        return true;
       }

  });
  buttonPanel.add(vfm);
  buttonPanel.add(new LabelField("  "));

  VerticalFieldManager vfm1=new VerticalFieldManager();
  vfm1.add(new BitmapField(e3.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){

        Dialog.alert("Members");
        return true;
       }

  });
  buttonPanel.add(vfm1);

  VerticalFieldManager vfm2=new VerticalFieldManager();
  vfm2.add(new BitmapField(e4.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){

        Dialog.alert("Message");
        return true;
       }

  });
  buttonPanel.add(vfm2);

  VerticalFieldManager vfm3=new VerticalFieldManager();
  vfm3.add(new BitmapField(e5.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){

        Dialog.alert("Settings");
        return true;
       }

  });
  buttonPanel.add(vfm3);

  VerticalFieldManager vfm4=new VerticalFieldManager();
  vfm4.add(new BitmapField(e6.getBitmap(),FOCUSABLE){
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){

        Dialog.alert("Logout");
        return true;
       }

  });
  buttonPanel.add(vfm4);

  manager.add(buttonPanel);

  setTitle(manager);
```

Comment: I have this code and I tried it.It is not tab bar but it is similar to that.

Comment: you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942225/tab-bar-in-blackberry-without-toolbarmanager ?

Comment: Yes but the it doesnt run on my simulator.I cant see its icon image n simulator after running it.(I have three classes Loadingscreen.java,BottomPanel.java,PictureBackgroundButtonField.java and MyApp.java)

Comment: I Tried it.Code is runing but its icon is not appearing on simulator.

Comment: I use default icon in res folder

Comment: I am talking about my application icon.Its not coming on simulator after running it.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot something. create new class within constructor which pushscreen the other class which extends main screen

example:

```
public class MyApp extends UiApplication{
public MyApp(){        
    pushScreen(new LoadingScreen());
}    }
```